# Sorting Event Teams

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to rank teams for a robot competition. They will compete in 3 stages. They have a total score and duration in each stage. Sample data comes as follows:

[sample image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCx36.png)

If I don't have to compare time, then python's "max ()" function works.

```
data["max"] = data[["stage1","stage2","stage3"]].max(axis=1)
```

I use the "sort_values" method of the pandas library to sort them. In order to rank the teams, I must find the best score in 3 stages. If I am not looking at the time, I can find the best score by inserting the points in the max method but if the points are equal, I should compare them with the best time they have. In order to be able to make the best score and time to get enough.

For the create data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

data = pd.DataFrame()

puanlar=[]
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    puanlar.append(sayi*random.randrange(1,100))
puanlar2 = []
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    puanlar2.append(sayi*random.randrange(1,100))
puanlar3 = []
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    puanlar3.append(sayi*random.randrange(1,100))
data["stage1"] = puanlar
data["stage2"] = puanlar2
data["stage3"] = puanlar3

dakika=[]
saniye = []
salise = []
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    dakika.append(random.randrange(1,4))
    saniye.append(random.randrange(1,60))
    salise.append(random.randrange(1,60))

data["stage1_minute"] = dakika
data["stage1_second"] = saniye
data["stage1_millisecond"] = salise
dakika=[]
saniye = []
salise = []
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    dakika.append(random.randrange(1,4))
    saniye.append(random.randrange(1,60))
    salise.append(random.randrange(1,60))

data["stage2_minute"] = dakika
data["stage2_second"] = saniye
data["stage2_millisecond"] = salise
dakika=[]
saniye = []
salise = []
for sayi in np.ones(100):
    dakika.append(random.randrange(1,4))
    saniye.append(random.randrange(1,60))
    salise.append(random.randrange(1,60))

data["stage3_minute"] = dakika
data["stage3_second"] = saniye
data["stage3_millisecond"] = salise
data["max"] = data[["stage1","stage2","stage3"]].max(axis=1)
data.sort_values(['max'], ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Please please don't post sample image of data. Spend sometime to type part of it in the post, or provide data generation code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm sorry for the variable names, but I've added the code.

Comment: have you seen the Pandas documentation on [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)? Also, for the time, i would convert everything to milliseconds before sorting.

Comment: Yes, I will find the maximum value and duration that I received after using it, but here is the problem: I don't know which stage is the highest

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not get you fully. In the question you say you are trying to *rank* the teams. In the above comment you imply that you want to find the *stage* with the highest value. Could you clarify? maybe edit your question with a clarification. I **feel** pandas can do what you want, but I dont get what you want fully.

Comment: I edited and tried to be descriptive. Thanks for feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create some sort of combination of the corresponding columns and find max:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
data_len = 1000
data = pd.DataFrame({'stage1': np.random.randint(1,10, data_len),
                     'stage2': np.random.randint(1,10, data_len),
                     'stage3': np.random.randint(1,10, data_len),
                     'stage1_min': np.random.uniform(1,4, data_len),
                     'stage1_sec': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len),
                     'stage1_mil': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len),
                     'stage2_min': np.random.uniform(1,4, data_len),
                     'stage2_sec': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len),
                     'stage2_mil': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len),
                     'stage3_min': np.random.uniform(1,4, data_len),
                     'stage3_sec': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len),
                     'stage3_mil': np.random.uniform(1,60, data_len)})

# combination
for i in range(1,4):
    prefix = f'stage{i}'
    data[prefix+'new'] = [(stage, -m,-s, -ms) for stage, m, s, ms in zip(data[prefix],
                                                                       data[prefix+'_min'],
                                                                       data[prefix+'_sec'],
                                                                       data[prefix+'_mil'])]

data['max'] = data[[f'stage{i}new' for i in range(1,4)]].max(axis=1)
```

You can also use `idxmax()` for the index of the row with max.

Comment: really nice and concise solution. I am trying to learn from it. If you have some time, would you please explain how does putting the columns in a tuple affect the max method?

Comment: @SpaceMonkey55 it's just the problem is really comparing tuples, i.e., (1,2) > (1,1). Since OPis looking at best time as tier breaker, flipping the sign of the time works, i.e. (1, -1) > (1, -2).